# Proving the simple form of a function from statistical mechanics

Tags: real-analysis, statistical-physics, functional-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have discovered a pertinent solution to my problem in the article *On the Kinetic Theory of Rarefied Gases* by Harold Grad and the book *Thermodynamik und Statistik* by Arnold Sommerfeld, both of which present the same proof for the issue I was addressing. The proof assumes the continuity of the function $f$.

---

Suppose we have a function $f_0:{\mathbb R}^3\rightarrow {\mathbb R}_+$ that satisfies the following property

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\mathbf{v}_1^2 + \mathbf{v}_2^2 = \mathbf{v}_1'^2 + \mathbf{v}_2'^2\newline
&\mathbf{v}_1 + \mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{v}_1' + \mathbf{v}_2'
\end{split}
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
f_0(\mathbf{v}_1)f_0(\mathbf{v}_2) = f_0(\mathbf{v}_1')f_0(\mathbf{v}_2')
\end{equation}

**Question**: Under what conditions, such as continuity, smoothness, or even analyticity as assumed by physicists, can $\log f_0$ be written as a linear combination of $v^2$, the three components of $v$, and an arbitrary constant?

$f_0$ originates from Boltzmann’s distribution of particles in the velocity space, which specifies the equilibrium state in the absence of external forces in classical statistical mechanics. The two equalities represent the conservation laws of kinetic energy and momentum, respectively, in a collision between two perfectly elastic spheres. I encountered $f_0$ in the book *Mathematical Statistical Mechanics* by Colin J. Thompson.

Here is the original text from the book

> Taking logarithms of both sides of Equation 6.1 we have
> $$
> \log f_0({\bf v_1})+ \log f_0({\bf v_2}) = \log f_0({\bf v_1’}) + \log f_0({\bf v_2’}) 
> $$
> which has the form of a conservation law. Since for spinless molecules (e.g., hard spheres) the only conserved quantities are energy and momentum (and constants), it follows that must be a linear combination of $v^2$ and the three components of $v$, plus an arbitrary constant, i.e.,
> $$
> \log f_0({\bf v})= \log A-B({\bf v}-{\bf v_0})^2
> $$

I cannot see a rigorous proof provided to explain it, nor are any reference bibliographies given, despite the book being titled "Mathematical Statistical Mechanics"…

Comment: What is $v_1^2$ when $v_1$ is an element in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: the inner product of the vector with itself is meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can indeed prove this for reasonable functions, $\log f_0\in C^2$, say.

Let me write $F=\log f_0$. By replacing $F$ by $F(v)-C-d\cdot v$, we can also assume that $F(0),\nabla F(0)=0$.

If $a,v$ are orthogonal, then, by assumption,
$$
F(v)+F(a)=F(v+a)+F(0)=F(v+a) ,
$$
and for small $a$, we have $F(v+a)\simeq F(v) +a\cdot\nabla F(v)$, $F(a)\simeq a\cdot\nabla F(0) =0$. This shows that $a\cdot \nabla F(v)=0$ for all $a$ with $a\cdot v=0$. In other words, $\nabla F(v)$ has the same direction as $v$. It follows that $F$ is radial since for a fixed sphere, the directional derivatives tangential to the sphere are zero. We have $F(v)=g(x^2+y^2+z^2)$, if $v=(x,y,z)$.

On the other hand, we can again decompose $v=xe_1+(ye_2+ze_3)$, and our basic assumption gives $F(v)=g(x^2)+g(y^2+z^2)$. So $g$ satisfies [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) $g(s+t)=g(s)+g(t)$, and this implies that $g(r^2)=cr^2$, as desired (for example, take the $s$ derivative at $s=0$ in the functional equation to conclude that $g'$ is constant).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have now discovered another proof that is even simpler and yields a stronger result. It is completely elementary! You can find it, for example, in Harold Grad's article *On the Kinetic Theory of Rarefied Gases* or Arnold Sommerfeld's book *Thermodynamik und Statistik*. The proof assumes the continuity of the function $f$ and derives its vanishing from the existence of five zeros $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(-1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 5):

The cited authors *assume* that there are only three linearly independent summation invariants,$^\ast$ $Q_1(\mathbf{v})=1$, $Q_2(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v}$, and $Q_3(\mathbf{v})=|\mathbf{v}|^2$. Then if the function $\log f(\mathbf{v})$ is a summation invariant, it must be a linear combination of $Q_1$, $Q_2$, and $Q_3$ [otherwise, $\log f$ would be a fourth independent summation invariant, counter to the assumption].

This assumption that $Q_1$, $Q_2$, and $Q_3$ are the only linearly independent summation invariants is phrased in the cited text as "the only conserved quantities are energy and momentum and constants". If the physics of the problem allows for a fourth summation invariant, for example $Q_4=|\mathbf{v}|$, then $\log f$ could also contain terms linear in $|\mathbf{v}|$.

---

$^\ast$ A summation invariant is a function $F(\mathbf{v})$ which is conserved upon collision, $F(\mathbf{v}_1)+F(\mathbf{v}_2)=F(\mathbf{v}'_1)+F(\mathbf{v}'_2)$.

Comment: So you are saying that the OP's claim about $f_0$, as a mathematical statement, is false? Could you then give a counterexample?

Comment: The OP has only one invariant function, $f_0\otimes f_0$ -- not the three functions $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ in your answer. It is unclear to me why you say "You need to *assume* that there are only three linearly independent summation invariants,$^\ast$ $Q_1(\mathbf{v})=1$, $Q_2(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v}$, and $Q_3(\mathbf{v})=|\mathbf{v}|^2$" and "Then by definition [what definition?], if the function $\log f(\mathbf{v})$ is a summation invariant, it must be a linear combination of $Q_1$, $Q_2$, and $Q_3$."

Comment: If you assume that the space of invariant functions is spanned by the Qs — this is the statement that only kinetic energy and momentum and constants are conserved — then the result follows easily. This explains what the text is saying, but it doesn’t answer the mathematical question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Indeed, there exists a proof demonstrating that there are only five linearly independent **continuous** summation invariants. You can find it, for example, in Harold Grad's article *On the Kinetic Theory of Rarefied Gases* or Arnold Sommerfeld's book *Thermodynamik und Statistik*.